# How to categorize unanswered questions of user from a chatbot?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I want to store the unanswered question of user and categorize them into different classes, the unanswered question will be saved in a excel file.

Comment: Add a flag (set to False by default) to all questions. Change it to True when a question is answered.

Comment: actually what I'm trying to do is , I want to store all the unanswered question as a string or text in a excel file then these unanswered questions will be categorize in the basis of keyword (suppose somebody asked a question related to "price" and there is no predefined ans but as the keyword "price" is there it will be fall in to "price related unanswered question"  )@sumit

Comment: Your question is not very clear, I would suggest please add all technical details to the question as well as what you have and what kind of result you expect. Please help us to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you have a list of categories? You already mentioned price, what about past, future, profit, loss etc…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary of lists with the categories

```
categories = {
        "price": [],
        "size": [],
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Then go through each categories.keys() and search each key in each question and then append to the list.

```
for q in questions: #list of questions
    for k in categories.keys():
        if k in q:
            categories[k].append(q)
```

It will give you a dictionary of categorised questions.
But questions can be repeated in several categories, be careful. (you can pop those questions out)